# Как в Debian изменить часовой пояс?

Tags: linux, debian

Установил Debian с официального американского сайта. У меня в нем стоит не московское время. Команда `date` показывает `Fri Dec  2 16:28:14 UTC 2016`. Как мне поменять настройки времени средствами терминала?

Comment: в следующий раз при установке выбирайте сразу нужный часовой пояс.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выполните команду от имени пользователя root:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```